# Neo4j BatchInserterIndex OutOfMemoryError exception

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, neo4j, batch-insert

I'm using the [BatchInserter](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.1/javadocs/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserter.html) to get specific properties and relations from the neo4j database to write a new index (with numeric indexes) using the [BatchInserterIndex](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.1/javadocs/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserterIndex.html).

after ~10 minutes the index folder has a size of 4.7G, the memory is fully used, the garbage collection makes it very slow and after some more time the VM ends with an Garbage Collector Exception.

the code looks roughly like this:

```
    final BatchInserter bInserter = BatchInserters.inserter(this.dbStoreDir, getConfig());
    final BatchInserterIndexProvider bIndexInserterProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(bInserter);
    final BatchInserterIndex bIndexInserter = bIndexInserterProvider.nodeIndex(indexName, getConfig());
    try {
        final Map<String, Object> propMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (final Long id : idSet) {
            this.filterProperties(bInserter.getNodeProperties(id), propMap);
            for (final BatchRelationship rel : bInserter.getRelationships(id)) {
                if (rel.getType().name().equals(ANYREL)) {
                    final Long subNodeId = rel.getEndNode();
                    this.filterProperties(bInserter.getNodeProperties(subNodeId).entrySet(), propMap);
                    this.filterProperties(bInserter.getRelationshipProperties(rel.getId()).entrySet(), propMap);
                }
            }
        bIndexInserter.add(id, propMap);
        propMap.clear();
        }
    } finally {
        bIndexInserter.flush();
        bInserter.shutdown();
        bIndexInserterProvider.shutdown();
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getConfig() {
        final Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put("dump_configuration", "false");
        config.put("cache_type", "none");
        config.put("use_memory_mapped_buffers", "true");
        config.put("node_cache_size", "2G");
        config.put("relationship_cache_size", "800M");
        config.put("neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory", "200M");
        config.put("neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory", "200M");
        config.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "200M");
        config.put("neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory", "500M");
        config.put("neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory", "250M");
        config.put("neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory", "250M");
        config.put("type", "exact");
        return config;
    }
```

I use the following Java VM options:

```
-D64 -Xmx13G -Xmn1G -server -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

on a machine with 16GB RAM and Java 1.7_60

a) Am I doing something wrong?

b) What is taking all that memory? Is it lucene or neo4j?

c) What is Michael Hunger doing differently in his [batch importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20) ? I had a small look in the code but I really don't get a clue on how he's doing it..

Comment: Can you check that your propMap doesn't grow indefinitely? Move it inside the loop. You didn't share your filter methods

Comment: I looked again over my property filter which just filters out some properties and creates numeric ValueContext objects, also I measured the object size (http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/util/ObjectSizeEstimator.html) which did not show any problems. Downgrading to Neo4j version 2.0.2 solved the problem. I'm gonna do another test with building the database from scratch with Neo4j 2.1.2 and report back if the problem persists.

Comment: The index builder described above works flawlessly in neo4j 2.0.2! I just tested again the case of rebuilding the index. Using neo4j 2.1.2 and the "allow_store_upgrade=true" property (which upgrades the database before executing the index builder) the memory problem comes up.

Comment: Running again into this problem with total different code... If i read this right: "http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-io-examples.html#configuration-batchinsert" the batch inserter can only insert data that fits completely into memory ??